# How can I make a portable curses interface?

Tags: python, terminal, python-2.x, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to make an interface in Curses in Python, but I was wondering how could I make it more portable when the window's terminal increases while the script is being executed.

For example, this code in a window `(height:80,width:24)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import curses
import time
stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
curses.noecho()
stdscr.keypad(1)

try:
# Run your code here
    height,width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    num = min(height,width)
    for x in range(num):
        stdscr.addch(x,x,'X')
    stdscr.refresh()
    time.sleep(3)
finally:
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
```

would work and would be portable with any window (it would print many 'X' chars for the entire window's size), but if I resize it in a second time during its execution it wouldn't work and it would be empty for some parts of the terminal.

How can I make it work the way I want?

Comment: Theres's a signal that tells you when the window size changes called `SIGWINCH` so I guess you would need to catch that and get the new size and redraw your curses stuff... somehow:-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you please show an example?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to handle `SIGWINCH` (using ncurses) by calling `getch`, which will return `KEY_RESIZE` when ncurses gets interrupted by `SIGWINCH`.

Further reading:

- [Signal Handlers](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) (`initscr` manual page)
- [Predefined key-codes](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) (`getch` manual page)
- [15.11. curses — Terminal handling for character-cell displays](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html), which mentions its interfaces to ncurses' various resize-related functions.